# Three.js load multiple separated objects / JSONLoader

Tags: javascript, json, three.js, blender

is it possible to load a scene (e.g. two different cubes) exported from blender to json and identify them?

I need to distinguish between them e.g. to make one rotating and the other moving.

Thank you in advance!

Denv

edit+++

Thank you for your answer!

So if I load two cubes in one JSON file:

```
loader.load("untitled1.js", function(geometry, materials) {  
        mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
        mesh.scale.set( 10, 10, 10 );
        mesh.position.y = 0;
        mesh.position.x = 0;
        scene.add( mesh );       
});
```

How can I move first cube?

```
mesh.getObjectById(0).position.x = 15;
```

Doesn't seems to work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

#### Yes, it is possible to load an entire scene from a json file exported from Blender!

I achieved that with the following process: *(Using three.js r80)*

1. First you have to name your different objects in Blender like in the following image Outliner.
2. Then you can export the file using Three.js json exporter add-on for Blender, but taking care of marking the ***Scene*** checkbox like in the following:

[image: **Image**: In Blender (Steps 1 and 2)]

3. Using this option your json file *now contains all the meshes* on the Blender's Outliner, as you can verify using any text editor. It doesn't matter if the meshes were selected or not.
4. It is important to know that the *root* (or parent) object isn't a ***Geometry*** anymore. It is labeled with the ***Object*** type by now. To access the children objects (of *Mesh* type) you can use the **getObjectByName** method on the *root* object like in the following code:

   ```
   jsonloader.load( "obj/Books.json", function ( loadedObj ) {
       var surface = loadedObj.getObjectByName("Surface");
       var outline = loadedObj.getObjectByName("Outline");
       var mask = loadedObj.getObjectByName("Mask");
       // Watch the objects properties on console:
       console.log(loadedObj);
       console.log(surface);
       console.log(outline);
       console.log(mask);
   } );
   ```

   If we check the browser's console, we can see the proper objects assigned. And from now, you can manipulate the children objects independently (move, rotate, change materials, etc.)

[image: **Image**: Json Structure and Console Output (Steps 3 and 4)]

Answer (score -1):

Each object loaded has an associated .id. So you can use the Object3D.getObjectById() to find it and apply transforms on it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

So if I load two cubes in one JSON file:

    loader.load("untitled1.js", function(geometry, materials) {  
            mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
            mesh.scale.set( 10, 10, 10 );
            mesh.position.y = 0;
            mesh.position.x = 0;
            scene.add( mesh );       
    });

How can I move first cube?

    mesh.getObjectById(0).position.x = 15;

Doesn't seems to work.

Thank you!

Comment: I am sorry but before the edit it was not clear that you wanted two cubes from one json file. Never the less, you can name your cubes inside blender and then use the getObjectByName() to access them.

Comment: Hi @gaitat i tried load more than one object by using `getObjectById()` it is not working

Comment: you should really explain yourself when down voting a correct answer

Comment: @JothiKannan *2 years later* a solution is to use `loader = THREE.ObjectLoader(); loader.load('path/to/objects.json', function (objs) { obj1 = objs.getObjectByName('name_of_obj'); });` following @Jaime 's answer, you can see how you can name the object in Blender, then use that name in JS to get that object which you can then add to the scene, etc