# Loading multiple objects in Three.js from Blender

Tags: three.js, blender, mesh

I have a quite complex shape (dressed girl) that in Blender is broken down into different objects and it's loaded into Three.js with the JSON loader (with a little hack I made, that uses zipped files instead of just JSON files, as there are a lot of vertices).

As I want to change dynamically the style of the dress from a Web page, I was wondering how I can show/hide different pieces (e.g. sleeves) in the scene.

I tried traversing the `THREE.Mesh`, but there are no children.

When I export from Blender with the JSON exporter, I don't see anything referring to the names of the objects in the JSON. Is the structure lost?

Comment: I saw this question and noticed that you got openctm to work with Blender. I was wondering if you could answer my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23073947/importing-model-into-three-js-performance. It seems to me that the openctm scripts don't work with Blender 2.7.

Comment: Similar issue , got one model.js and cant separate the meshes once i have loaded it...for example i have 5 objects in the one file but cant access them individually :myobject.children " item1" cant seem to work it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using meshes containing lots of vertices, I would advise you to use the openCTM webGL loader instead of zip hacking. Here is a link to the loader : http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_ctm.html 
This mesh compression tool uses LZMA compression method and can reduce the size of your files by 93%...

Concerning the JSONLoader, using an array might help:

```
var meshes = [];
...
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
var onGeometry = function(geom)
{
    var mesh = new THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject(geom, [material]);
    meshes.push( mesh );
    ...
    scene.add(mesh);
};

loader.load("yourfile.js", onGeometry);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hey Qt, thanks, but I was trying to understand how to load from a single file, all of the objects, as they are in Blender. The number of objects I'd have to load would 1) create a mess in my code and 2) have a greater overhead while loading.

Comment: Yep, I've done it. In the end I did as you suggested, I changed my workflow to have less meshes. And using OpenCTM. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that. Good luck for your project.

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question. What if `yourfile.js` includes multiple meshes?

Comment: Well this array thing certainly doesn't work @r72 when loading a json file which has exported "Scene" in it, containing multiple meshes.

Answer (score 1):

**It is possible to load an entire scene with several meshes from a json file exported from Blender and handle them separately!**

*You can follow the complete process of exporting a entire scene from Blender and the right way of handling the exported meshes on my [answer of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39402449/4595374).*

So, you can get the **different meshes and manipulate them separately** using the `getObjectByName` method. But it is important to know that the loaded object isn't a *Geometry* anymore. It is labeled with the *Scene* type by now and it must be handled in a different way.

The loading code must look like this one:

```
    loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load( "obj/Books.json", function ( loadedObj ) {
        var surface = loadedObj.getObjectByName("Surface");
        var outline = loadedObj.getObjectByName("Outline");
        var mask = loadedObj.getObjectByName("Mask");
        scene.add(surface);
        scene.add(outline);
        scene.add(mask);
    } );
```

Besides, you can handle the **multiple materials of single mesh** using `THREE.MeshFaceMaterial` like in the following code:

```
var mat1 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { map: texture1 } );
var mat2 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { map: texture2 } );
var materials = [mat1, mat2];
var faceMat = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials);
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, faceMat );
scene.add( mesh );
```

Hope this helps :)