# Accessing multiple objs using .getObjectById() with JSONLoader in Three.js

Tags: javascript, json, three.js, blender, loader

Is it possible to differentiate between the meshes within one .js file exported from blender and animate them separately using Three.js?

The cube I would like to select is named "Cube" loads properly. However, when I try to get it by Name or Id, it doesn't recognize the var item1.

```
loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

loader.load('engine.js', function (geometry, materials) {
  var mesh, material;

  material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials);
  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  mesh.scale.set(1, 1, 1);

  var item1 = scene.getObjectByName("Cube");
  item1.position.x = 15;

  scene.add(mesh);
});
```

I found this post but it seems unresolved:  [Three.js load multiple separated objects / JSONLoader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16357384/three-js-load-multiple-separated-objects-jsonloader)

What is the best approach to loading multiple meshes via JSONLoader? I'd prefer to load them together as one .js file and just select the ones I would like to animate.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your blender scene you need to name every mesh you want to access independently in three.js. Then you can use Object3D.getObjectByName() to access your mesh in three.js.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I stumbled across some blogs which talked about using SceneLoader().  Is it better for loading multiple groups of meshes? What are the pros and cons of either method? Thanks again for your time and effort!

Comment: So to be clear since I'm new to javascript. Are you suggesting that I access my mesh named in blender as "item1" and move it with the following code? : Object3D.getObjectByName("item1").position.x = 50;   Unfortunately this doesn't work.

Comment: `Object3D.getObjectByName()` is the signature of the function. You would use it as you have in your code (as long as your objects come with a name from blender).

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, it is possible to load an entire scene with several meshes from a json file exported from Blender!**
*You can see the complete process described on my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16357384/three-js-load-multiple-separated-objects-jsonloader/39402449#39402449) of the [cited post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16357384/three-js-load-multiple-separated-objects-jsonloader)*

So, you can differentiate between the meshes using the `getObjectByName` method and manipulate them separately. But it is important to know that the loaded object isn't a *Geometry* anymore. It is labeled with the *Scene* type by now and it must be handled in a different way.

You must change the loading code for one like this:

```
    loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load( "obj/Books.json", function ( loadedObj ) {
        var surface = loadedObj.getObjectByName("Surface");
        var outline = loadedObj.getObjectByName("Outline");
        var mask = loadedObj.getObjectByName("Mask");
        mask.scale.set(0.9, 0.9, 0.9);
        scene.add(surface);
        scene.add(outline);
        scene.add(mask);
    } );
```

In the above code we can indeed animate the *surface, outline and mask* meshes independently.